# uGet has a problem while downloading some file and always retry until it reached the limit

Tags: dns, hostname, uget

Here's the error messsage :

- Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
- Resolving timed out after 15528 milliseconds
- Closing connection 1

  ---
- Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
- Resolving timed out after 15529 milliseconds
- Closing connection 2

and loop more..

How do i solve this issue?

Comment: Your DNS is broken and needs fixed and repaired.  It can't find the DNS for the host name and as such fails to connect since it can't resolve.

Comment: @ThomasWard I had the same problem for one month. Files could download directly from google chrome but couldn't download by uget. Finally, I deleted all uget config files. I don't know why but It solved the problem.

Comment: @ICE perhaps so, however the information provided the OP indicates that it's not able to resolve hostnames, and is timing out on that resolution which *sounds* like a DNS issue.

Answer (score 0):

One of these options can solve the problem.

1. Close Uget and Delete `.config/uGet` folder. then open uget and see the problem solved.
2. using aria2 instead of curl. go to the uGet settings `edit>settings>plug-in` and change `plug-in matching order` to the `aria2` or `aria2+curl`

If you don't have aria2:

```
sudo apt-get install aria2
```